# SQL: Use Group BY two times

Tags: sql, oracle

My table looks like this:

```
INSERT_DATE | WorkOrder_ID | Status
```

It is a log-table where every status change for one WorkOrder is inserted. So one WorkOrder_ID occurs multiple times with different statuses.
What i want to do is: to select the 'Count' of Work-Orders per day and per WorkOrder_ID.
So I need two group bys: one for the day and one for the WorkOrder_ID

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For workorder in a day you could use

```
 select INSERT_DATE , count(distinct WorkOrder_ID ) 
 from my_table 
 group by INSERT_DATE
```

and for WorkOrder_ID  and date

```
select INSERT_DATE ,  WorkOrder_ID , count(*) 
 from my_table 
 group by INSERT_DATE , WorkOrder_ID
```

and for all WorkOrder_ID

```
 select  WorkOrder_ID , count(*) 
 from my_table 
 group by WorkOrder_ID
```